# PHP avoid double foreach when looping into an array of an array

Tags: php, foreach

I have this kind of array:

```
Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Lskdjlkdsfj [start_time] => 2013-06-12 [timezone] => Europe/Rome [location] => Rome, Lazio [id] => 592087844156650 [rsvp_status] => attending ) ) [paging] => Array ( [previous] => https://graph.facebook.com/100004042705860/events?limit=25&since=1370995200&__paging_token=592087844156650&__previous=1 [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/100004042705860/events?limit=25&until=1370995200&__paging_token=592087844156650 ) )
```

To get the data I am doing so:

```
    foreach ($fb_events as $data) {
    foreach ($data as $fb_event_data) {
        echo $fb_event_data['name'];
        echo $fb_event_data['start_time'];
    }
}
```

Is this the best way to do it, using a double foreach? Is there a better way to loop into an array of an array?
This one is working. I am just wondering if I am doing it the "right" way!

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with loops inside of loops; that's exactly how I'd do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the top level array only has a single element then this can be simplified as

```
foreach ($fb_events["data"]  as $fb_event_data) {
    echo $fb_event_data['name'];
    echo $fb_event_data['start_time'];
}
```

Comment: that not the point of the question

Comment: I do the same whenever it's possible ... much more clear and understandable.

Comment: @donald123 Based on the supplied code and data my code is exactly what the OP is trying to perform. Iterating through the top level elements is going to yield arrays that don't have a name or start_time key and give undefined index notices

Answer (score 3):

While there is nothing wrong with using nested loops. In some cases you might want to solve looping in a more elegant way. Take a look at PHP's [RecursiveArrayIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php) and [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) classes for that.

```
$foo = array(
    'data' => array(
        'name' => 'Lskdjlkdsfj', 
        'start_time' => '2013-06-12', 
        'paging' => array(
            'previous' => 'some-url'
         )
     )
);

$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveArrayIterator($foo) );

foreach ($it as $key => $val) {
    echo $key . ":" . $val . "\n";
}

name:Lskdjlkdsfj
start_time:2013-06-12
previous:some-url
```

Answer (score 1):

Nested loops are no more "right" or "wrong" than nested arrays are. That is to say, it depends entirely upon your data and its meaning.

If you end up with five levels of nested loops, you might want to reconsider the structure of your code. But I don't think one level of nesting is *ipso facto* a problem.