# How to make foreach not looping the latest 2 values

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, foreach

I have an array of an array that I need to loop.
Here is the sample:

```
Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Paul van Dyk @ Cream Amensia Opening Party, Ibiza [start_time] => 2013-06-13 [timezone] => Europe/Madrid [location] => Amnesia Ibiza [id] => 553728968001075 [rsvp_status] => attending ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Lskdjlkdsfj [start_time] => 2013-06-12 [timezone] => Europe/Rome [location] => Rome, Lazio [id] => 592087844156650 [rsvp_status] => attending ) [2] => Array ( [name] => Paul van Dyk @ Cream - BCM, Mallorca [start_time] => 2013-06-12 [timezone] => Europe/Madrid [location] => BCM Planet Dance [id] => 182367615251136 [rsvp_status] => unsure ) ) [paging] => Array ( [previous] => https://graph.facebook.com/100004042705860/events?limit=25&since=1371081600&__paging_token=553728968001075&__previous=1 [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/100004042705860/events?limit=25&until=1370995200&__paging_token=592087844156650,182367615251136 ) )
```

Now this is what I am doing: I am looping with two foreach inside the arrays and getting the data. The problem is that [next] and [previous] are not to be included in the loops or the result will get having strange happenings by passing the wrong values inside the variables. Especially the variable $fb_event_data['id'] that will not get the right value on the last two loops..

```
$fb_events = $facebook->api('/me/events/');
  foreach ($fb_events as $data) {
        foreach ($data as $fb_event_data) {
    $event_info = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fb_event_data['id'].'/?access_token='.$fb_user_details['fb_token']));  

          echo $event_info->description."<br/>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see that there is another array over than those before inside the array. So what I am doing wrong in my code?: [paging] => Array ( [previous] => https://graph.facebook.com/100004042705860/events?limit=25&since=1371081600&__paging_token=553728968001075&__previous=1 [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/100004042705860/events?limit=25&until=1370995200&__paging_token=592087844156650,182367615251136 ) )

Comment: Instead of describing what this code does, tell us what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to get only the data relative to event in the array and not the previous and next values that are giving bad results to my code

Comment: @DiegoPucci See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071233/php-avoid-double-foreach-when-looping-into-an-array-of-an-array/17071318#17071318)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to get the data key of the events so use this.

```
foreach ($fb_events["data"]  as $fb_event_data) {
    $event_info = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fb_event_data['id'].'/?access_token='.$fb_user_details['fb_token']));  
    echo $event_info->description."<br/>";
}
```